# how to read data from excel sheet in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to get data from 1st column 7th row till 20th column from excel sheet using robot framework selenium. Below is the code which i tried to perform the task:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
${path_excel}   D:\\Users\\thejav\\Desktop\\Robot_framework.xls

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open the Excel

*** Keywords ***
Open the Excel
    open Excel    ${path_excel}     
    ${my_data}=    Get Column values    Robot_framework    0    
    Log    ${my_data}
```

Answer (score 2):

For my sugesstion if you want to store alot data , you should use LIST . You can find my example below :

```
 *** Settings ***
    Library           Selenium2Library
    Library           ExcelLibrary
    Library           Collections

    *** Variables ***
${path_excel}   D:\\Users\\thejav\\Desktop\\Robot_framework.xls

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open the Excel

*** Keywords ***
Open the Excel
    ${my_data_as_list}=    Create List
    open Excel    ${path_excel}
    :For    ${i}    in range     7       20

    \   ${my_data}    Read Cell Data By Name    Robot_framework    A${i}
    \   Append To List    ${my_data_as_list}      ${my_data}

    Log    ${my_data_as_list}
```

Comment: @tejashreev Pls check my code agian . i just edited.

Comment: ExcelLibrary is very cool Library to Play with Excel data in Robot Framework. Supporting all kind of Excel operations like -

1- Read/Write data in Excel
2- Get Row Count/Column Count
3- Add or Remove sheets and so on.
and Compatible with Robot Framework :)